How to Draw Annotations in OHIF Viewer from Saved World Coordinates in Database?
I am currently working on a medical imaging project using the OHIF viewer to display and annotate 3D images. I use cornerstone3D's lengthTool to do annotations in MPR view, and I can save the world coordinates of these annotations to my database.
Here is what I can do so far:

Users can create annotations on 3D images in the OHIF viewer.
I can save the world coordinates of these annotations to my database.
I can retrieve the saved annotations from the database when the study is loaded.

My current challenge:
I need to draw these annotations back onto the 3 viewports in the OHIF viewer.
Details:

The annotations are stored as world coordinates in the format { x: Number, y: Number, z: Number }.
I am using Cornerstone and CornerstoneTools for rendering and handling the annotations.
I understand how to fetch data from my database, but I am unsure how to transform these world coordinates back into the viewport and display them as annotations in the OHIF viewer.

Thanks a lot

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
